# Face feature extraction and recognition

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, face-recognition, feature-extraction

I am using Visual Studio 2010 with C++.

I wish to capture a face using webcam to extract features and then saved it. After that i want to check by scanning a face using the webcam if the face matches with the initially stored face. Real time shall be used here.

In short i am creating a database instantly and then recognizing it (assume only 1 face is stored here). If matches or not, to execute respective functions.

I need a simple guide and help to get started here, or is there any available code/algorithm for such situation which can be refer to ? Thank you very much.

Comment: OpenCV has face detection built-in. Once you get some thing up and working, please post your code for further problems.

Comment: "(assume only 1 face is stored here)" - you will need more, probably a dozen or such.

Comment: Why cant i deal with just 1 face?

Answer (score 1):

You can use OpenCV for this, Check out the link below for more details

http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/